# Как проверить строку на соответствие шаблону?

Tags: delphi, строки

Имеются строки в текстовом файле (текст для примера):

```
21.01.2018.nomer1:134887 
Adres://ru.stackoverflow.com
21.01.2018.nomer2:234887 
Adres://ru.stackoverflow.com
21.01.2018.nomer3:334887 
Adres://ru.stackoverflow.com
```

Нужно, что бы на выходе, получить результат:

```
21.01.2018.nomer1:134887
21.01.2018.nome2r:234887 
21.01.2018.nomer3:334887
```

Делаю вот так:

```
ReadLn(fall, S);
// то есть задаю условие - типа фильтра, то есть обязательное условие:
if (Pos('.', s,1) > 0)
and (Pos('.', s,2) > 0)
and (Pos('.', s,3) > 0)
and (Pos(':', s,4) > 0) then
  writeln(f1, S);
```

Но не срабатывает.

Как задать обязательную последовательность в функции Pos - если в тексте существует **точка + точка + точка и знак двоеточия** (и символов в строке после двоеточия **не должно быть больше 7**) то такая строка записывается? То есть копировать только те строки которые соответствуют этому параметру.

Comment: `TRegEx` в помощь

Comment: @teran, Натолкнули Вы, меня на мысль в общем сделала. И оформила ответ, спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хотите скорости - делайте разбор строк руками, через указатели и посимвольную обработку (пример: функция `_DoScan` в коде ниже). Но тут нужна определённая сноровка и можно наделать кучу багов (даже за код в примере я не ручаюсь на 100%).

Хотите удобства и гибкости, тогда регулярные выражения ваши верные друзья (правда, регулярки ещё надо уметь составлять).

В примере ниже представлены два варианта разбора строк, с замерами производительности каждого из вариантов. Вариант с регуляркой работает примерно в 15 раз медленнее (примерно 290 мс. против 4100 мс. на 5 млн. итераций).

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Character,
  System.RegularExpressions,
  System.Diagnostics;

const
  GTestCount = 1000000;

var
  GTestData: array [0..5] of string = (
    '21.01.2018.nomer1:134887',
    'Adres://ru.stackoverflow.com',
    '21.01.2018.nomer2:234887',
    'Adres://ru.stackoverflow.com',
    '21.01.2018.nomer3:334887',
    'Adres://ru.stackoverflow.com'
  );

function _DoScan(
  var P: PChar;
  const ASep: Char;
  const ADigitsCountFrom: Integer;
  const ADigitsCountTo: Integer
): Boolean; inline;
var
  VCount: Integer;
  VDoDetectDigits: Boolean;
begin
  VCount := 0;
  VDoDetectDigits := (ADigitsCountFrom > 0) or (ADigitsCountTo > 0);

  while (P^ <> #0) and (P^ <> ASep) do begin
    if VDoDetectDigits then begin
      if Char(P^).IsDigit then begin
        Inc(VCount);
      end else begin
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    Inc(P);
  end;

  Result := (P^ = ASep);

  if Result then begin
    if VDoDetectDigits then begin
      Result := (VCount >= ADigitsCountFrom) and (VCount <= ADigitsCountTo);
    end;
    if ASep <> #0 then begin
      Inc(P);
    end;
  end;
end;

function DoTest: Integer;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  P: PChar;
  VStopWatch: TStopwatch;
begin
  Result := 0;

  VStopWatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

  for J := 0 to GTestCount - 1 do begin
    for I := 0 to Length(GTestData) - 1 do begin
      P := PChar(GTestData[I]);
      if
        _DoScan(P, '.', 1, 2) and
        _DoScan(P, '.', 1, 2) and
        _DoScan(P, '.', 1, 4) and
        _DoScan(P, ':', 0, 0) and
        _DoScan(P, #0, 1, 6)
      then begin
        Inc(Result);
        //Writeln(GTestData[I]);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Writeln(VStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
end;

function DoTestWithRegExpr: Integer;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  VRegExpt: TRegEx;
  VStopWatch: TStopwatch;
begin
  Result := 0;
  VRegExpt := TRegEx.Create('\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4}\..*?:\d{1,6}', [roCompiled]);

  VStopWatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

  for J := 0 to GTestCount - 1 do begin
    for I := 0 to Length(GTestData) - 1 do begin
      if VRegExpt.IsMatch(GTestData[I]) then begin
        Inc(Result);
        //Writeln(GTestData[I]);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Writeln(VStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
end;

begin
  try
    Writeln(DoTest);
    Writeln(DoTestWithRegExpr);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: ,Отличный вариант. Я только что заметила ответ.... Очень Вам благодарна!

Comment: zed,Начала разбираться с кодом а вот интересно как первый вариант, то есть DoTest - подключить к моему коду. То есть ReadLn(fall, S); ..... writeln(f1, S); Тут немного запуталась.

Comment: Если у вас строка для разбора находится в переменной `S`, то вам надо заменить ей все обращения к `GTestData[I]` из примера. Т.е. после `Readln` сделайте `P := PChar(S);`.

Comment: zed, Спасибо, разобралась, все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, додумалась я - как решить задачу **через регулярные выражения**. Кому интересно то ответ вот такой будет:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}
```

Comment: Регулярка ускоряет и упрощает разработку, но замедляет исполнение программы. Если важна скорость обработки, то тогда лучше парсить строку руками (тем более, что она довольно простая). Если же скорость регулярок устраивает, то Ok.

Comment: @zed, Да, вчера увидела, тоже, что регулярные выражения, для файлов в 30 мегабайт, очень медленно работают.  А какие еще есть варианты, ну может функции?

Comment: А  MatchesMask  ?

Comment: @MBo Поиск по маске `*.*.*.*:*` работает примерно в 2 раза быстрее регулярки, но всё ещё более чем в 5 раз медленнее ручного разбора строки.

Comment: @zed Да, примерно такого результата и следует ожидать.

Comment: @MBo, Уже сделала через MatchesMask.